# Paste Mulitple cell values into a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the values of a range of cells(A1:A50) into a single cell (B1). I can do it manually by copying the cells to the clipboard and then pasting the clipboard into the formuala bar of B1 but I can't find a way of doing this in a macro other than getting the cells copied to the clipboard.

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
Selection.Copy
```

I would like the contents of cell B1 to look something like this:

Value of cell A1

Value of cell A2

Value of cell A3

...and so on

Comment: [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) a 1d-array first maybe. You can do so through `Transpose` *or* if your range are not all of type constant, try to loop and concatenate values.

Comment: How do you want to join the A column values? Comma separated? Mashed? Newline? What type of value do you want in B1? String? You can read A1:A50 into an array, use the JOIN function to create a string and set the .VALUE2 property of B1 to the result. We need more information, though, to give a more complete answer.

Comment: I need each cell to be pasted on to a new line (in the same way it was copied from the column (a1:a50). Cell B1 is formatted text.

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: I’m using Excel 2010

Comment: Excel 2010? As far as I remember, there was no textjoin then. It's a pity. You could solve your problem with a simple formula `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);FALSE;A1:A50)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
Sub myConcat(rSource As Range, rTarget As Range, Optional sDelimiter = vbCrLf)
Dim oCell As Range
Dim sRes As String
    sRes = vbNullString
    For Each oCell In rSource
        sRes = sRes & sDelimiter & oCell.Text
    Next oCell
    rTarget.Value = Right(sRes, Len(sRes) - Len(sDelimiter))
End Sub
```

Call it from your code like as

```
Sub tst_myConcat()
    Call myConcat([A1:A50], [B1])
End Sub
```

Of course, this procedure can be easily converted to a function:

```
Function myConcat(rSource As Range, Optional sDelimiter = vbCrLf)
Dim oCell As Range
Dim sRes As String
    sRes = vbNullString
    For Each oCell In rSource
        sRes = sRes & sDelimiter & oCell.Text
    Next oCell
    myConcat = Right(sRes, Len(sRes) - Len(sDelimiter))
End Function
```

In this case, just write in the target cell (B1) `=myConcat(A1:A50)`

Do not forget to include in the cell format [**Wrap text**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-alignment-of-text-in-a-cell-6426fdc3-e0da-41f9-bfe1-82f064a9696c#bkmk_control)!

[image: myConcat WrapText.gif]

Comment: Hi John.
Thanks for you help on this. The code you supplied does work but just not in the way I hoped. Your method strings all the cells together into one long line of text. Is there a way to paste the column range (a1:a50) into the cell B1 but still keep the same format/layout? This would mean cell b1 would contain the value of cell a2 below the value of a1.
Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: @Patrick Are you saying that you now see the result as one long line of text? Don't worry, it just looks like this - there are actually 50 rows in a cell right now. You just need to kick Excel for it to display the result correctly. I added this to my answer. (By the way, I changed the `vbCr` constant to `vbCrLf` - this should make the code work correctly in different versions of Excel, both in 2010 and hopefully even in 2003)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I changed the vbCrLf to vbLf which seemed to give me the result I was looking for. Other than that, it was perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### First Column To String

- The `FirstColumnToString` function (`UDF`) has a fixed delimiter (`Delimiter`) which can manually be changed. But it can e.g. do the following:

  ```
  =FirstColumnToString(A1:A2,A4,A6:C8,Sheet2!A1:A3)
  ```

  where it will discard error values and zero-length strings (`""`) and choose only values from the first column of each range e.g. in range `A6:C8` it will choose the values from `A6:A8`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function FirstColumnToString(ParamArray SourceRanges() As Variant) _
         As String
    
    Const Delimiter As String = vbLf & vbLf
    
    Dim RangesCount As Long
    RangesCount = UBound(SourceRanges) - LBound(SourceRanges) + 1
    Dim data As Variant
    ReDim data(1 To RangesCount)
    Dim Help As Variant
    ReDim Help(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim Element As Variant
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    For Each Element In SourceRanges
        j = j + 1
        If Element.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            data(j) = Element.Columns(1).Value
        Else
            data(j) = Help
            data(j)(1, 1) = Element.Columns(1).Value
        End If
        RowsCount = RowsCount + UBound(data(j))
    Next Element
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To RowsCount)
    Dim Current As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    For j = 1 To RangesCount
        For i = 1 To UBound(data(j))
            Current = data(j)(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Current) Then
                If Current <> vbNullString Then
                    k = k + 1
                    Result(k) = Current
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    ReDim Preserve Result(1 To k)
    
    FirstColumnToString = Join(Result, Delimiter)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way of doing the job is to use the TREXTJOIN function in Excel:

```
With Sheet2.Range("A1:A50")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Sheet2.Range("B1").Value2 = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(vbCrLf, True, _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    .AutoFilter
End With
```